# Is it possible to get the calculated transform:scale value from nested divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When DIVs are nested with a css3 scale factor the scale values multiply. What is the best way get the current value from nested DIVs? As far as I understand it's not possible to get the value with a simple javaScript DOM query, right?

Here is a simple example. The current scale from the inner DIV is 0.8*0.5, but I would like to get this value with a simple function or something. Any Ideas?

```
<div id="scale08" > Scale 0.8

    <div id="scale05" > what global scale do I have?</div>


</div>

#scale08{
    background:green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transform:scale(0.8);
}

#scale05{
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B4Uxn/

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Write a function (A) given a DOM element, returns the scale value (1 if it hasn't been changed or no scaling present)

Write a function (B) given a DOM element, returns 1 if the DOM element is the document element, or the value returned by calling the first function (A) with the DOM element multiplied by this function (B) called with the DOM element's parent.